# Load file in pig based on whitespace

Tags: regex, file, apache-pig, whitespace, delimiter

I am trying to load a file in PIG which 2 words may be separated with spaces or tabs (may me more than one). Is there a way to delimit the file load using a regex for whitespace? Or is there any other way to achieve the below?

**Input:**

```
COUNTESS    This young gentlewoman had a father,--O, that`
```

**Output:**

```
COUNTESS  
This  
young  
gentlewoman  
had  
a  
father,--O,  
that
```

It would be great to have a comma delimiter also, but that would make it more complex. For now, only the whitespace delimiter should work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Load the file as a line and then use [TOKENIZE](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/func.html#tokenize).If you have a mixture of tabs and space then after loading the data add a step to replace the tabs with spaces in the line and then use TOKENIZE.

```
A = LOAD 'test2.txt' as (line:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(A.$0));
C = FOREACH B GENERATE TOBAG(*);
DUMP C;
```

**OUTPUT**

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know PIG, but here's some info:

https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/func.html#strsplit

```
STRSPLIT(string, regex, limit)
```

regex could be something like `[\s,]+`.  That will split on any blocks of whitespace and commas.  So for instance, `a b,c ,d, e` would split in to each letter.  the order of space and comma does not matter.